# Invalid JSON: undefined in CouchDB with python sockets

Tags: python, json, couchdb

I wrote this python script which should compose an http request as a string and send it on a socket connected to couchDB:

```
import socket
import json

DB_IP = '127.0.0.1'
DB_PORT = 5984

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.connect((DB_IP, DB_PORT))

db_name = 'temperatures'
doc_id = 'today'

request = "PUT /" + db_name + "/" + doc_id + " HTTP/1.1\n"
request += "Content-Type: application/json\n\n"
request += json.dumps({'min_t': 10, 'max_t': 20})

sock.sendall(request)

result = sock.recv(4096)

print result
```

the output is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/19)
Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 20:07:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 48
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

the couchdb log is:

```
[debug] [<0.575.0>] 'PUT' /temperatures/today {1,1} from "127.0.0.1"
Headers: [{'Content-Type',"application/json"}]
[debug] [<0.575.0>] OAuth Params: []
[error] [<0.575.0>] attempted upload of invalid JSON (set log_level to debug to log it)
[debug] [<0.575.0>] Invalid JSON: undefined
[info] [<0.575.0>] 127.0.0.1 - - PUT /temperatures/today 400
[debug] [<0.575.0>] httpd 400 error response:
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
```

I bet the error is in the http request string because the exact same query works fine with Postman, but I can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the Content length header, as it seems CouchDB can't guess the length of your JSON body.

```
json_data = '{"min_t": 10, "max_t": 20}'
request = "PUT /" + db_name + "/" + doc_id + " HTTP/1.1\n"
request += "Accept: application/json\n"
request += "Content-Length: " + str(len(json_data)) + "\n"
request += "Content-Type: application/json\n\n"
request += json_data
```